# Binding Alt-Shift-. in tmux

Tags: linux, shell, tmux, kde, konsole

I'm trying to bind some key combinations in `tmux`, this is what I have in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -n 'M-S-.' next-window
```

This doesn't work. How can I bind it?

I'm running Konsole in KDE Plasma, Debian 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `M->`? Shift is only used as a modifier for some functions keys, any key where Shift sends a different character you will bind that instead.